# Cannot center equation using $$

Tags: math-mode, equations

Hello I have the following two equations:

- `$CR^m_n=$ ${n+m - 1}\choose{m}$ $=\frac{(n+m+1)!}{(n-1)!m!}$`
- `$C^m_n=$ ${n}\choose{m}$ $=\frac{n!}{(n-m)!m!}$`

When I try to center them adding `$$` at the beginning and the end it doesn't work

Here is the code

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside]{book}
\begin{document}
    $$CR^m_n=$ ${n+m - 1}\choose{m}$ $=\frac{(n+m+1)!}{(n-1)!m!}$$
    $$C^m_n=$ ${n}\choose{m}$ $=\frac{n!}{(n-m)!m!}$$
\end{document}
```

Which I get error.

How can it be done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should never use `$$` in LaTeX, nor `\choose`. However, the main problem is that you use `$` inside something that's already in math mode.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside]{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{gather*}
  CR^m_n=\binom{n+m-1}{m}=\frac{(n+m+1)!}{(n-1)!\,m!} \\
  C^m_n=\binom{n}{m}=\frac{n!}{(n-m)!\,m!}
\end{gather*}

\end{document}
```

Note the thin space `\,` between the two factorials.

[image]

Please, take your time and check on some introductory material to LaTeX:

https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8477/4427

By the way, the syntax for `\choose` would be

```
{n+m - 1\choose m}
```

but `\binom` is definitely better.